My animation in Roblox Studio plays, but in a actual Roblox game it dosen't play, but the projectile works
My Problem is that the animation I labelled as FireballThrow and the fireball projectile does play in the Roblox Studio environment, HOWEVER, in a real game it doesn't execute properly, only the projectile is successful.
Here is my original code:
My Local Script (Below) in the StarterPack folder:
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local cooldown = false
local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local RS = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local mouse = player:GetMouse()


UIS.InputBegan:Connect(function(Input,gpe)

    if Input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.E and not gpe and not cooldown then
        print("Skill Thrown")
        cooldown = true
        local animation = player.Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid"):LoadAnimation(script.FireballThrow)
        animation:Play()
        wait(.5)
        RS.ThrowRemote:FireServer(mouse.Hit.p)
        game.Debris:AddItem(animation,2)
        wait(2)
        cooldown = false
    end

end)

And my server side script (Below) in ServerScriptService:
local remote = game.ReplicatedStorage.ThrowRemote

remote.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player,MousePosition)
    local fireball = game.ReplicatedStorage.Fireball:Clone()
    fireball.Parent = workspace
    fireball.CFrame = player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame * CFrame.new(0,0,-2)

    local NewForce = Instance.new("BodyForce")
    NewForce.Force = Vector3.new(0,workspace.Gravity * fireball:GetMass(),0)
    NewForce.Parent = fireball

    fireball.Velocity = CFrame.new(player.Character.HumanoidRootPart.Position,MousePosition).LookVector * 70

    fireball.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
        if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") and not hit:IsDescendantOf(player.Character) then
            hit.Parent.Humanoid.Health -= 50 -- You can choose how much damage they take
            fireball:Destroy()
        end
        wait(4)
        fireball:Destroy()
    end)

end)

I used RemoteEvents to trigger the server-side script.
The animation for the fireball is nested in the local script, and the RemoteEvents and fireball model are in Replicated Storage.
I've tried reaching out to other people who have made other functions to the code that work but the animation still doesn't work which is kind of the main thing. Most things I've managed to fiddle around with is getting the animation to run within Roblox Studio itself.
I'm not too advanced with Lua as I've been teaching myself here and there and wanted to make a game for myself to have on my portfolio of things I've created. Any help with explaining where I may be going wrong would be much appreciated.

What is the asset ID for the FireballThrow animation and is it public? You should make sure your place has access to the animation.
